# using eval and background a process in the same line in Fish

Tags: fish

How can I use eval to execute the command in a variable and also background it in the same line? I'm trying the following but it's not working. For example `s xeyes` I would expect the shell to return.

```
function s --description "Start a command in the background and remove from jobs list"
    echo (count $argv)
    if test (count $argv) -ne 1 
        echo "illegal number of parameters"
        return 1
    end
    eval $argv[1] 2>&1 > /dev/null &
    disown
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fish does not support backgrounding functions. `eval` is a function, so backgrounding it is not supported.

You need to put the `&` into the eval'd code, so

```
    eval $argv[1] 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

*might* work.

Alternatively, since fish 3.0 `eval` isn't needed here anymore, so you can just do

```
 $argv[1] 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```